# Table-building Javascript function causes error on page load

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, onload

Recently, I have been trying to somewhat dynamically create a table in html that contains all of the files in a certain folder.  I decided to make a batch file to create a text file that contains a list of all the files, and then use the generated text file in a javascript function to fill the table.

The function `showDownloads` is called on page load, and throws the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at showDownloads (script.js:8)
    at onload ((index):9)
```

However, if I run `showDownloads()` from the console, it properly generates the table without throwing any errors.

```
var downloadPath = "../builds/dev-versions/";
var downloads;

function showDownloads() {
  getData();
  var table = document.getElementById('downloadTable');

  for (var i = 0; i < downloads.length; i++) {  //Error happens here
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    for (var j = 0; j < downloads[i].length; j++) {
      var cell = document.createElement('td');
      var file = document.createElement('a');
      file.setAttribute('href', downloadPath + downloads[i][j]);
      file.setAttribute('download', downloads[i][j]);
      file.innerHTML = downloads[i][j];

      cell.appendChild(file);
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    table.appendChild(row);
  }
}

function getData() {
       var xmlhttp;

       if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
           xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
       }
       else {
           xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       }

       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
           if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
             var lines = xmlhttp.responseText;

             intoArray(lines);
           }
       }

       xmlhttp.open("GET", "devFiles.txt", true);
       xmlhttp.send();
}

function intoArray (lines) {

   var lineArr = lines.split('\n');
   lineArr.pop();

   downloads = new Array(lineArr.length / 2);

   var j = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i < lineArr.length; i += 2) {
     downloads[j] = [lineArr[i], lineArr[i + 1]];
     j++;
   };
}
```

Why is the array `downloads` considered undefined during the first call?

Why isn't it created with the call to `getData`?

Comment: It is created.... its just async.... And since you do not use `promises` and `.then` your code continues before your `getData()` actually gets the data. At a later point (by the time you open console and type things, it is there so it works.

Comment: Ahhh...  I was unaware that this could be an issue.  As I am relatively inexperienced in programming, I assumed that `getData()` would by default be completed before moving on.  I will look into `promises` and `.then`, thanks.

Comment: `getData` does get completed, but due to the nature of how you've written your `getData` the result of the said function is not present in the `downloads` variable. Namely, the event handler `onreadystatechange` which is used to handle HTTP requests is, as it's name says fired once the readystate changes, which does not necessarily come before you attempt to access `downloads` variable. Matter of fact it will definitively not fire before you attempt to access it. This is why it is important to undestand the difference between sync and async.

Comment: I looked into `promises`, and ended up finding the `fetch` API for JavaScript.  I implemented this on my site and everything in now working.  Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine it's an async issue, the for loop doesn't wait for getData to finish, so on page load, downloads is still empty, but by the time you try it in the console, downloads WILL have finished and stored the data in downloads. Since it's a global variable, it's probably actually processing the data from the previous data fetch when you run it in the console.